# Mark Self Answered postings accordingly

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, accepted-answer, self-answer, highlighting

### Summary

I think it would be beneficial to mark self answered posts, where people only "ask" the question in order to share their knowledge/findings, in a way so that it is obvious to everyone checking the question out that this is not really a question that is seeking an answer. And most importantly: that the answer given is indeed the one that solves the problem for the person that asked the question.

Why do I think this would be beneficial?

- This would prevent someone from investing time, trying to help OP to find a solution (note that we can only mark our own answer as the correct one after two days (on Stack Overflow) so it is not immediately obvious that the provided answer is sufficient already)
- It could prevent some people from downvoting either the answer or the question itself

Especially the last bit tends to be very frustrating.

### The story behind this question

Let's consider an example of mine: *[Message "error: use of undeclared identifier 'assert'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64184499/error-use-of-undeclared-identifier-assert/64185433#64185433)*

At first glance this problem looked like dozens of other questions already posted on Stack Overflow (I know, because I did indeed try to find an answer there before). In my particular case however my situation was slightly different. Therefore after having failed to find a solution with existing Stack Overflow questions, I decided to share my findings after I had figured it out.

The solution turned out to be very specific to my problem, but it seemed reasonable enough that someone else might run into the same issue, so I decided to share it nonetheless.

Me posting this self answered "question" resulted in the following

- My question getting downvoted (as there was no comment made as to *why*, I have to guess: I think someone saw the question and though "This has been asked here before" and thus downvoted)
- My answer getting downvoted (again without explanation, so here's my guess: The answer doesn't seem to be very general and without taking into account who the question actually asked, it could create the impression as if this was just a pseudo answer trying to catch a few accidental upvotes or something like that)
- Another answer was created (that contained the standard answer for the standard problem, that I however did not have). Given that I wasn't looking for another answer in the first place, this just means that someone invested some time trying to help, where there was nobody actually seeking help.

I think chances are that all of this could have potentially been prevented if the question was marked as Q&A-style immediately after posting.

### How could this "marking" look like?

I am not a good UI/UX designer, so there are probably better ideas for this, but here is my suggestion:

- Change the background color of the question and the original author's question to something that is different from the standard background. This should create a connection between the question and the answer that is only present if the question was "asked" in a self answered manner
- Add a label somewhere next to the question stating that this is self answerd-style (optionally including a short explanation of what this means)
- Accept the written answer immediately, so it is clear that the problem has been resolved

Comment: Other answers are to be encouraged always. Just because you weren't looking for that alternative answer doesn't mean nobody else is. The audience for Q&A is everyone.

Comment: I don't mean to discourage answer per se. I just want to be sure that nobody invests time in this because they think they are helping OP out of a problem. If you think you have a _better_ or _different_ answer than already posted, then by all means: share it. But I have the impression that people assume that if a question as an answer that is not marked as _accepted_ yet,  that answer does not properly address the question and thus might feel obliged to help. I just want that it is immediately clear that this is not the case for Q&A-style postings. I definitely don't want to inhibit answering.

Comment: But that's my point we really shouldn't answer questions to help the OP, we should answer to help everyone. The needs of the many outweigh the needs of the one. Even having an accepted answer shouldn't put anyone off for that same reason.

Comment: Okay then that is fine. What about the issue with the downvotes then? I feel like if someone is trying to share their findings one should think about using different criteria to decide when to downvote a question/answer.

Comment: downvotes mean what they say on the tooltip. Your answer is not useful. Perhaps the standard way is the standard way for good reason.

Comment: That seems like a very poor explanation to me. Being "useful" in terms of a Q&A question is basically out-of question as the answer given _is_ useful. More or less by definition. You might argue about downvoting the question, but doing so for the answer seems like someone anticipating that the solution that OP has found, is not useful for OP. I mean I also won't downvote someone's answer to a question just because it didn't help _me_. I only do so, if I think this is unhelpful to OP _and_ me _and_ everyone else that might visit the question

Comment: Please note that the quality standard for a "normal" Q/A and a self-answered Q/A is the same. Your example question could benefit from an MCVE. The issue I see is, that the question can most likely only be answered correctly by guessing.

Comment: @honk Well that's my point though. It is not intended to be answered by others. Thus nobody else is actually required to reproduce this locally. All that is required from this question is enough information to be able to recognize the problem when searching for a solution to an issue that you are having yourself

Comment: Please read the first sentence of my last comment again :)

Comment: I did - but it seems we have a different opinion on that :)

Comment: Well, I'm not sure whether this a matter of opinion. I have seen complaints similar to yours on Meta (especially MSO) and the answers basically said that you can't apply a different standard to your question just because you know the answer. Well, you can, but then you should not wonder about downvotes ;)

Comment: It is probably not the first time this has happened. What turned up in your research?

Comment: Original blog post (though it doesn't contain much guidance): *[It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)*

Comment: @honk I guess this really comes down to the point of view that you want to take on this. Yours seems to be that a Q&A question should be asked in a way that allows others to answer it. Mine is that a Q&A question should be seen as sharing my findings and thereby documenting the solution.

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q you mean when I originally searched for answers to the problem of the linked question?

Comment: Related: *[What's wrong with my self-answered question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180845)*

Comment: Quoting from the linked Q&A post: "never hesitate to ask and answer your own question on any Stack Exchange site". Putting up restrictions of having to create boilerplate code that serves no other purpose than to pretend I really need someone to reproduce my issue in order to help me because otherwise my question will be downvoted seems like a very good reason to hesitate imo

Comment: @Raven how can you share your findings if you can't give a good and comprehensive explanation of your problem? This is really key to the concept of sharing information. No-one will benefit from your solution if it is unclear what problem it is solving. Also if a question lacks details it will, and should, be closed for that. Closure is often a route to deletion.

Comment: @Luuklag the included error message makes the problem easily recognizable for everyone searching for it and I also provided the extra information that I did not make the standard mistake of not including the assert headers. Imo that's enough for sharing the information. When I look for answers, I never try to replicate OP's problem. I try to see if I can get the solution to work for my specific problem

Comment: Well this example of yours is indeed a bit different, and it would suffice as a question, albeit a very mediocre one. Also I can't help but feel that your answer has plenty of potential homes in the network. There are a lot of questions about this error message, and your answer would have multiple questions to which it could be added. Simply state there that the presented solution didn't work for you, and that the thing you did solved the problem. There really was no need for a new question.

Comment: *"It is not intended to be answered by others."* If that's really the case, then perhaps it doesn't belong on Stack Exchange. The Help pages on every site state that (in theory) self-answered questions are welcome, but such Q&A pairs are supposed to be evaluated like regular questions and answers, they do *not* get special privileges.

Comment: (cont) However, many regulars seem to hold self-answered Q&A pairs to a higher standard, since they are often used as canonical dupe targets. So when you post such a pair it's probably a good idea to post a brief comment on the question to that effect, and perhaps to explain why this Q&A pair is useful. Also, the body of your question should contain links to related questions, and explanations as to why they don't adequately cover your case.

Comment: @Luuklag I feel like posting an answer to a question that clearly will not be solved by that answer is way worse than creating a new question...

Comment: _Yours seems to be that a Q&A question should be asked in a way that allows others to answer it._ Well, to my understanding this is a core feature of SE. _Mine is that a Q&A question should be seen as sharing my findings and thereby documenting the solution._ The most frequent reply I have seen to that view is: "Maybe a personal blog would be more suitable for you." Anyway, I think you would have a better time playing by the rules than insisting on your opinion ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring I used to add a comment in the question that this is a Q&A-style question but it always got edited out by someone shortly after. Thus I stopped doing it. Being obliged to document the entire research leading to that question is a rather high barrier. I would consider that to be the distinction between a "normal" question and a "good" one but nothing that should be necessary in order to avoid _downvotes_.

Comment: There is no guarantee to avoid downvotes. Even excellent questions get them. Perhaps someone mis-clicked, or doesn't like you or the topic. There is only one way to prevent them, and that is not posting.

Comment: @honk I am not trying to insist on anything. I was just thinking that this could be an improvement to the site, which it appears the majority here does not agree with. That's fine. The suggestion to create my own blog seems very off for several reasons (imo), but given that you are merely quoting here, let's not start a discussion on that :)

Comment: @Luuklag yes absolutely. But as I stated in my post I do think that this could decrease the _likelyhood_ of them happening. But this is of course under the assumption that self-answered questions should have slightly different quality standards than regular ones, which I believe should be the case but which does not seem to be an opinion shared by many here. From that point of view my suggestion does indeed not make sense.

Comment: That's why I said to post that info in a comment: they can only be edited or deleted by mods. ;) You don't need to post *all* your research, but you should post links to a few relevant related questions (& say why they aren't adequate dupes), so people know that you've done due diligence on checking that it's not a dupe. And to reduce the likelihood that someone will attempt to dupe-close your question with those targets. ;)

Comment: FWIW, here's a Python example Q&A posted to act as a good dupe target for a fairly common problem which gives rather baffling error messages if you don't realise what the real error is. https://stackoverflow.com/q/36250353/4014959 The OP is a room owner of the SO Python chatroom, and we discussed the creation of this Q&A in chat before it was posted. It got a couple of downvotes within minutes of being posted, and a couple more after that comment (by another room owner) was posted. But as you can see, the Q&A have managed to accrue very healthy scores... and 210 linked questions.

Answer (score 5):

> I think it would be beneficial to mark self answered posts, where people only "ask" the question in order to share their knowledge/findings, in a way so that it is obvious to everyone checking the question out that this is not really a question that is seeking an answer. And most importantly: that the answer given is indeed the one that solves the problem for the person that asked the question.

There's already a mechanism for this: You can see how many answers a question has, and if you accept your own answer *to show that it solved your problem*, it will show that your question has an accepted answer. Here are two examples of the MSE questions page: The first one is self-answered, and as such showed up from the beginning with the '1 answer' box. The second one shows what that box looks like when the answer is accepted: it's very green.

[image]
[image]

In other words: If you don't want to waste your time on already answered questions, you don't have to! You can just click on the ones that have zero answers and aren't closed.

> This would prevent someone from investing time, trying to help OP to find a solution (note that we can only mark our own answer as the correct one after two days (on Stack Overflow) so it is not immediately obvious that the provided answer is sufficient already)

Even if you have accepted your answer, this doesn't stop people. [This question of mine](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/381497/are-there-any-tricks-to-getting-auto-petters-quickly-after-the-community-center) on Arqade still got another answer after I already wrote AND accepted my own answer.

Like people said in the comments already, your question isn't just there to help you. It's also there to help future visitors. If you have hacked together your own solution that's fine, but if someone else knows a different way of doing the same thing, having a second answer is good. Especially if that answer can explain why it does things differently from your own.

Having people invest time on already answered questions can be good, and should not necessarily be prevented: The first answer isn't always the best one.

> It could prevent some people from downvoting either the answer or the question itself

I doubt that. Self-answered questions are the same as regular questions in that regard: Your question and answer should meet the site's standards. Just because you posted it together with an answer doesn't automatically mean your question is a good question for the site.

The kind of self-answered question I see the most is spam, then the next often seen category is low-quality, lacking details or off-topic. Again: Those don't meet the site guidelines, so they get downvotes, close votes, and flags. If your idea is going to prevent that quality control from happening, I'd rather take a pass on having it.

Comment: I know of this mechanism and I _do not want to stop people adding answers_ per se. I just want to be able to signal that the question already has an answer that solved the problem. And as I can't accept my own answer before 2 days have passed, I wanted to suggest a different kind of highlight for this.

Comment: @Raven The reason you can't accept your own answer within 48 hours of asking is so that *everyone has a fair shot at answering* [as given here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/369802). A different kind of highlight would only complicate matters, in that case, find the arguments for the 48 hour limit and argue against those for removal of the 48 hour limit. Still though, the only way to avoid anyone ever writing a different answer to your question is by having it closed, locked or deleted, none of which I can recommend. If people want to spend time writing better answers, let them!